# auth0 is giving me an encrypted jwt when i need a signed jwt

Tags: next.js, jwt, token, auth0

in my next js app I ask for the token like this:

```
import { getAccessToken } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default async function token(req, res) {
  try {
    const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res, {
        audience: 'https://localhost:5000'
      });
      
    res.status(200).json({ accessToken });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
}
```

And all the settings in auth0 are specifying using RS256 yet I still get a token wit the following headers:

```
{
  "alg": "dir",
  "enc": "A256GCM",
  "iss": "https://my-app.uk.auth0.com/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 can provide two different types of Access Tokens, `JWT`:s and `Opaque tokens`.

Opaque Tokens comes in a proprietary format and can only be used with the `/userinfo` endpoint of Auth0. These are used if you do not specify an Audience, because Auth0 assumes that there is no external audience, and the proprietary format can be used.

Try to include an **audience parameter** with your token request. Typically, this would be an external API, like a custom API you have registered in the dashboard.

Source reference: https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens/get-access-tokens

Comment: Thanks for your help. But can you see that I have tried to specify an audience. My flask app is running locally on port 5000 and is the intended recipient of the requests. I created an API entity in auth0 to this effect too. I just keep getting opaque tokens no matter what. I tried deleting everything in auth0 and starting again but no joy.

Comment: Is that audience also specified in auth0 as an API/client? (You need to match both protocol, host and port I think. )

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'm checking every setting and still getting opaque tokens. I tried a new API in auth0 and used "123" as the audience/identifier and updated this in my flask API too. Still no luck. in auth0 api settings I set all client apps to authorised. I am sending the audience as 123 in the getAccessTokenSilently() call from the front end.